# jquery datepicker inside modal dialog

Tags: jquery

This question has been asked but for different result. 
People have had trouble using the date picker inside the modal dialog box and making the date picker show up (using the z-index property).

However i have simply copied the js used to make the datepicker work from the foot, but in the  view for the modal popup. this then shows the date picker, but does not populate the selected input box with the selected date.

my code that works everywhere else is the following:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

and the input in the modal dialog class is datepicker.

Im not sure what the solution i am asking for would be really. as the function works everywhere and does indeed show up (suggesting the jquery is working) but just not populate the input box with the selected date....
any ideas? ........

```
function modalfollow()
{
$('<div>').dialog({
    title:  'Add Follow',
    height: '350', 
    width:  '400',
    open: function ()
            {
            $(this).load('<?=base_url();?>leads/add_follow/<?=$this->uri->segment(3);?>/');
            },         
    modal: true 
    });
// return false so <a> or <button> doesnt fire + reload page
return false;
}
```

this loads the modal box that loads the view.

it is at this level the datepicker does not work.

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this issue?

Comment: im not really sure how to to be honest. ill edit it with relevant script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you are setting up up your code but I have it working without any hard work in this fiddle.Do you have update panels?

**Markup**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" /></div>
<button id="opener">Show</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $(function () {

   $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
    }
});
$("#opener").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
 });
 });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/abidmix/dBLn5/1/)

Comment: I see your point and i think i just needed to recall all the js again in top of the view. however i just think the problem that exists is a similar issue to that that means the master CSS file also does not inherit to the loaded view. and i think my confusion is with doing this in MVC. Thanks anyway.