# Whats wrong with this datepicker? (jquery, knockout)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

Nice and simple [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/iiminov/88rafcfk/12/).

I have a problem with **datepicker** not showing up.

I found similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200740/jquery-datepicker-inside-modal-dialog) with [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/abidmix/dBLn5/1/).

However there is a twist with knockout but I am not seeing any errors.

```
$('#iDueDate').datepicker();
```

Being initialised right after

```
$('#divModal').dialog();
```

So I doubt its wrong call to initialise datepicker. jquery libraries also seem to be attached alright.

Anyone see anything wrong?

#### Update

Sorry forgot to mention that you need to click edit -> Due Date to get to a place where datepicker is meant to show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your #iDueDate input doesn't exist in the DOM when you load the datepicker. You need to call the $('#iDueDate').datepicker() after your dialog. Here the simple update in your fiddle:

```
  self.openCard = function (cardToEdit) {
        self.selectedCard(cardToEdit);
        $("#divModal").dialog("open");
        $('#iDueDate').datepicker();
    };
```

Comment: You good sir certainly know your stuff. Thanks you for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest i have no idea why your code doesn't work, but you can try this, maybe that works:

```
$("#divModal").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    dialogClass: "dnnFormPopup",
    minWidth: 475,
    open: function(){
        $('#iDueDate').datepicker();
    }
});
```

Comment: I must say the solution provided works flawlessly and for that I thank you. But I had to give it too @Nyxelio for pointing out why javascript was misbehaving.